# Mod_Rewrite to new URL using SOME (but not all) values from %{QUERY_STRING}

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Since our product has switched from one coding framework to another, we need to modify some callback URLs from old third-parties for backward compatiblity. Basically the following two should work:

```
/oldLms/index.php?r=controller/action&code=randomCode
/lms/?r=site/newEndpoint&code=randomCode
```

The old `oldLms` directory is non existing now. That's why we need htaccess to forward requests from the first to the second.

The improtant points are the following:

1. The `code` query param should be passed to the new URL as a query param.
2. The `r` query param should **not** be passed since we have already hardcoded a new `r` as target that will handle the new logic. Passing the old `r` (controller/action in this case) will confuse the new framework into thinking that we are requesting something else.

Here's where we are at the moment:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)r=controller/action(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)code=(.*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldLms/(.*) /lms/?r=site/newEndpoint&code=$4 [L,NC,QSA,R=302]
```

However, this doesn't seem to work since `$4` does not return the value of the `code` query string parameter from the original URL.

Comment: To catch the groups from conditions you need to use the percentage sign, like this `%4`.

Comment: Please, see my second important point. The `r` parameter should not be passed and using your approach it is. This is why the conditions are needed.

Comment: My comment is still valid regardless you're using `$4` where it should have been `%4` you should also remove `QSA` as it will append the old query string to it duplicating your resulting query string.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was not aware of the percentage sign-ed selectors. Just discovered that in this specific case it has to be `%2`, not `%4`. Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)r=controller/action(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)code=(.*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldLms/(.*) /lms/?r=site/newEndpoint&code=%2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

1. Removed [QSA] since it kept appending the full query string to the forwarded URL (including the `r` param).
2. Used `%number` instead of `$number` in the replacement URL to target selectors from the query string instead of from the original URL.

Also, in this case it had to be `%2` instead of `%4`.